# Button not working after I call the main form

Tags: java, netbeans

I called the main form from splash screen.

*code*

```
b1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                f.dispose();
                new Mole_Game().setVisible(true);
            });
```

But the button isn't working. I tried to fix using getcontentpane.

What syntax should I use so the function of my main form will work?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: if this is JavaFx, add action listener will make the button listen to another action in the app. You sohuld implement. button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> doStuff());

Comment: Removed image of code that is already present as text. Fixed grammar